# Suppose a ring R is a PID. What does this say about possible orders on the set of R?

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, principal-ideal-domains, ordered-groups

More explicitly, is there always some partial or total order we can apply to the set of R?

Comment: Every set can be totally ordered.

Comment: Can any finite set A be ordered in such a way max(A) makes sense?

Comment: Usually an ordered ring refers to a ring with an order on it, ≤, that satisfies $a ≤ b \implies ac≤bc$ and $(0 ≤ a$ and $0 ≤ b) \implies 0 ≤ ab$ for all $a,b,c \in R$. It'd help to know if you had that in mind, or if you just want an order on the underlying set that doesn't interact with any of the ring structure. If the former, I don't know. It's probably worth mentioning that all ordered rings (that respect the inequalities above) are infinite. Also, not every poset has a maximum since, in general, not all elements will be comparable.

Comment: Do you want to ask about orders which are compatible with the ring, making $R$ a [partially] ordered ring?

Answer (score 1):

Every finite set can be totally (even well) ordered. If you assume the Axiom of Choice then you can drop "finite" assumption. Also note that every set can be equipped with trivial "$x\leq y$ iff $x=y$" ordering (thanks to @AsafKaragila comment). But I assume you want the ordering to preserve the ring structure.

For the purpose of this answer I will use strict $<$ ordering instead of $\leq$ (these are equivalent). We shall consider the following condition:

$$\forall_{a,x,y\in R}\ x<y \Rightarrow a+x<a+y$$

This is in many cases impossible. For example consider $R=\mathbb{Z}_n$ (or any finite ring). Assume there is an ordering of $R$ that is compatible with the ring structure as defined above. If $0<x$ for some $x\in R$ then by induction $0<x<2x<3x<\ldots$. But this sequence has to repeat itself eventually (we have finite number of elements in $R$). Thus we obtain that $kx<kx$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This is a contradiction. In particular $0$ cannot be compared with any other element. But $0$ is not special, we can generalize it: if $x<y$ for some $x,y$ then $x-x<y-x$ (again by the property) and thus $0<y-x$ which is a contradiction by the previous statement.

In particular the only (strict) partial ordering on $R$ that is compatible with addition is when no two elements can be (strictly) compared. This is boring.

Note that for $n=p$ prime the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field thus PID.

Comment: If you just want "linearly ordered", then this is much weaker than the axiom of choice; and if you want "partially ordered", well, the equality relation is a partial order on any set. Just not a particularly interesting one in most cases.